# Nested documents in model struct

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, slice, mgo

Say I have a `UserModel` like so:

```
type (
    OrderModel struct {
         ID   bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
         ...
    }

    UserModel struct {
         ...
         // What do I store here? Is this an array of strings? An array of bson.ObjectID? Or an Array of OrderModel?
         Orders  []string        `json:"orders" bson:"orders"`
         Orders  []bson.ObjectId `json:"orders" bson:"orders"`
         Orders  []OrderModel    `json:"orders" bson:"orders"`
         ...
    }
)

func (user *UserModel) PopulateOrders() {
    orders := []OrderModel{}

    // Query orders and assign to variable orders to then be assigned the the user Object
    // {magic query here}

    user.Orders = orders
}
```

In MongoDB, an array of `ObjectID`s would be stored to reference the `OrderModel` documents. Later on, I have a function that will populate the `Order` documents like described above: `PopulateOrders`.

What is the best way for the case above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 2 separate fields, one for the slice of IDs, and one for the slice of lazily loaded objects.

Omit the lazily loaded object slice from saving. It could look like this:

```
type UserModel struct {
     // ...
     OrderIDs []bson.ObjectId `json:"orderIDs" bson:"orderIDs"`
     Orders   []OrderModel    `json:"orders" bson:"-"`
     // ...
}
```

Note that I intentionally did not exclude `Orders` from JSON serialization, as it is (may) be useful in JSON representation.